# How to filter an object using multiple parameters in the specification method?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, specifications

I am writing an online-store using `Spring-Boot` (`MVC`) and `Hiberbate`. I decided to use the `Jpa specification` to filter the list of objects. For example, filter *coffee* with parameters of *roast* and *type of coffee*. I did all the guide and everything worked for me, but with only one input parameter, roasting. How to add one or more parameters for the filter, please tell me...

For example my realisation:

```java
public class CoffeeSpecification {

    public static Specification<Coffee> getCoffeesByRoasting(String name) {
        return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
            Join<Object, Object> roastingJoin = root.join(Coffee_.ROASTING);
            return criteriaBuilder.equal(roastingJoin.get(Roasting_.NAME), name);
        };
    }}
```

Service:

```java
public PageDTO<DrinkDTO> findAllFilter(int page, int pageSize, String roastingName, String coffeeType) {

        PageRequest pageRequest = PageRequest.of(page, pageSize, Sort.by("price").ascending());

        final Page<Coffee> coffees = coffeeRepository
                .findAll(CoffeeSpecification.getCoffeesByRoasting(roastingName), pageRequest);

        return new PageDTO<>(drinkMapper.drinksToDrinksDTO(coffees));
    }
```

Controller:

```java
@GetMapping("/coffees")
    public PageDTO<DrinkDTO> getAllCoffees(@RequestParam(value = "page", defaultValue = "1") int page,
                                           @RequestParam(value = "page_size", defaultValue = "5") int pageSize,
                                           @RequestParam String roastingName) {

        return coffeeService.findAllFilter(page, pageSize, roastingName, coffeeType);
    }
```

Comment: In which entity `coffee` type is stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used `JpaSpecification` for filtering area based on `mobile` and `pincode` and using the following code to achieve the same

```
public class UserAreaMappingSpecifications {
    public static Specification<UserAreaMapping> userAreaMappingByFilter(String pinCode, String mobile) {
        return (Specification<UserAreaMapping>) (root, query, cb) -> {
            Predicate pinCodePredicate = Objects.nonNull(pinCode) ? cb.equal(root.get("pinCode"), pinCode) : cb.conjunction();
            Predicate mobilePredicate = Objects.nonNull(mobile) ? cb.equal(root.get("mobile"), mobile) : cb.conjunction();
            return cb.and(pinCodePredicate, mobilePredicate);
        };
    }
}
```

I have used predicates and combining them using and operator.

Possibly, you can also do with your implementation as well

```
public class CoffeeSpecification {

    public static Specification<Coffee> getCoffeesByRoasting(String name, String type) {
        return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
            Join<Object, Object> roastingJoin = root.join(Coffee_.ROASTING);
            Join<Object, Object> typeJoin = root.join(Coffee_.TYPE);
            Predicate rostingPredicate = criteriaBuilder.equal(roastingJoin.get(Roasting_.NAME), name);
            Predicate typePredicate = criteriaBuilder.equal(roastingJoin.get(Roasting_.TYPE), type);
            return cb.and(rostingPredicate, typePredicate);

        };
    }}
```

Hope I was able to solve your problem.

**Note:** You can use `or()` operator based on your requirement instead of using `and()` operator.